# Динамическая перерисовка страницы

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

```
//Представьте, делаем мы такую штуку:
<div style="width:500px;">123</div><!--500/1920-->
```

Допустим это четверть экрана. Дальше если окно сделать не в полный экран - 500px - уже не являются четвертью. Логично сделать ширину в %, но при изменении ширины окна все равно придется перезагружать страницу

С помощью JS возможно определить рабочую ширину экрана. Только приходиться выводит весь блок на JS. Типа

```
var heigth = ***;
var all_page = '<div style="width:'+heigth+'px;">123</div>';
документ_врайт(all_page );
```

Собственно вопроса 2:

1. как, минимально по коду передавать переменные из JS в стили в коде страницы?
2. как динамически изменять ширину блоков? т.е. браузер поменял ширину окна, нужно как то переписать переменную, и обновить ту часть к которой это относиться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Логично сделать ширину в %, но при изменении ширины окна все равно придется перезагружать страницу

Зачем перезагружать страницу? Если размер блока задан в процентах, то изменяться он будет динамически при изменении размеров окна или родительского блока.

> как, минимально по коду передавать переменные из JS в стили в коде страницы?

В первую очередь нужно забыть про `document.write()`. Во вторую - почитать про [DOM](http://learn.javascript.ru/dom), особое внимание уделив свойству [innerHTML](http://learn.javascript.ru/basic-dom-node-properties#innerhtml-содержимое-элемента), а также таким методам как [document.getElementById, document.getElementByTagName](http://learn.javascript.ru/searching-elements-dom) и т. п.

> как динамически изменять ширину блоков? т.е. браузер поменял ширину окна, нужно как то переписать переменную, и обновить ту часть к которой это относиться

Снова перечитать про DOM, на этот раз обращая внимание на свойство style.